# django wait for db operations to be complete

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a function that iterates over a list and if needed adds a django record and uses.save()

After that loop another function is called that accesses the table that just may or may not have had save operations done on it.

It seems that there are still pending saves when the second function is called.

Is there a method in django to wait for the current operations to be done or what is the best practice for this type of race condition?

I put a sleep in before calling the second function and it did happen to give it enough time to finish.  This is not good because the sleep is arbitrary.

Comment: Mind posting a minimal amount of relevant code? It might help get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: Django's db operations are not asynchronous, so this type of issue can't happen. Something else is going on.

Comment: Ok, thank you Daniel, I will dig deeper.

Comment: Sorry, thank you guys for being my rubber duck. I made a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Control the Commit yourself or see Perform [action after commit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/transactions/).

I had a similar problem, so I had to start a function that uses the data I've just saved with `ModelAdmin`. I do this with transaction.on_commit, as follows:

```
from django.db import transaction

def do_verification():
    # do stuff
    pass

@register(Revendeurs)
Class RevendeursAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        transaction.on_commit(do_verification)
        ...
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```